# Exporting Sqlite Tables to a File and Reimporting It in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to one click export and import Sqlite tables? I don't really have any code to show, since it's a simple Sqlite table with rows and columns. Is there a one click (onTap) solution in Flutter to export and import the whole table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic that you can use it with a single line of code, but you can use a package, something like this:

https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite_more/tree/master/sqflite_porter

https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite_more

Comment: Thank you, I wondered why there was almost no documentation on how to do it, it's a weird thing that it doesn't exist yet, it pretty much should be simple in theory. I guess I'll try it like this.

Comment: It's trivial because you're expected to know a bit about SQL-based relational databases, including the concepts of dumping a table to text, and loading text into a database.  Why should they redescribe the fundamentals of SQL in the SQLite docs, when most of it is the very same as every other SQL database?